# $\{x\in R \mid x^2=1\}$ and $\{x\in R \mid x^2=x\}$ have same cardinality

Tags: ring-theory

Let $R$ be a commutative ring with unity,$1$ in which $2$ is invertible. Prove that the sets $\{x\in R \mid x^2=1\}$ and $\{x\in R \mid x^2=x\}$ have the same cardinality.

I have tried this as follows :
if $2a=1$ for some $a\in R$ then we can show that the sets $\{x\in R \mid (x-a)^2=a^2\}$ and $\{x\in R \mid x^2=x\}$ have the same cardinality. But I couldn't proceed further. I think somewhere we need to use the fact that $(a-1)^2=a^2$.

Comment: For $R = \mathbb R$ the two sets are $\{-1, +1\}$ and $\{0,+1\}$, and I can think up a very simple "linear" function that maps one set to the other. I'll bet the same map would work for a general ring that has the properties you've specified.

Comment: There is a bijection from one set to the other. See Exercise 4 **(b)** on [midterm #2 in my Math 4281 class from Spring 2019](https://www.cip.ifi.lmu.de/~grinberg/t/19s/mt2s.pdf).

Comment: @darijgrinberg - Hmm, I didn't work out all the details, but checking your answer sheet, it looks like the function I was thinking of isn't quite right, but close enough to be "wiggled" into the right one.

Comment: @JonathanZsupportsMonicaC: Huh, really? A degree-$1$ polynomial over $\mathbb Q$ is uniquely determined by two values, so it should be the same function.

Comment: @darijgrinberg - Yeah, but there are two choices for the mapping if you're thinking of them as _un_-ordered sets. I think I'm going to have to sit down and write them out explicitly to be sure what's going on. I'll update in comments.

Comment: I think both of them work. The set of idempotents is preserved under the map $x \mapsto 1-x$.